# test problem in multiprocess_data_loader_test.py

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pytest, dataloader

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
"options",
[
    dict(max_instances_in_memory=10, num_workers=2, batch_size=1),
    dict(num_workers=2, batch_size=1),
    dict(max_instances_in_memory=10, num_workers=2, start_method="spawn", batch_size=1),
    dict(num_workers=2, start_method="spawn", batch_size=1),
    dict(max_instances_in_memory=10, num_workers=0, batch_size=1),
    dict(num_workers=0, batch_size=1),
],
ids=str,
)
def test_multiprocess_data_loader(options):
   reader = MockDatasetReader()
   data_path = "this doesn't matter"

   loader = MultiProcessDataLoader(reader=reader, data_path=data_path, **options)
   if not options.get("max_instances_in_memory"):
      # Instances should be loaded immediately if max_instances_in_memory is None.
        assert loader._instances
```

...
In the case max_instances_in_memory is None, the assert loader._instances is [] and it can not pass the test case. What are you expecting when you comment that **# Instances should be loaded immediately if max_instances_in_memory is None**. ?

Comment: Not sure what your question is - if the comment is correct? You should probably ask that the author of the code.

Comment: I am also not sure about the comment that it is right or wrong. In my case, I check the type of loader._instances to make sure it can return an empty list, not a None value

Comment: Yes, but what is your actual [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here?